# Conditionally ignore resource update

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-ssm

I have following SSM resource:

```
resource aws_ssm_parameter private_key {
  name      = var.name
  type      = "SecureString"
  value     = var.key
  overwrite = true
  tags      = var.tags
}
```

I have no control over what value of `var.key` is supplied, and it changes every time terraform runs. But I need to be able to prevent value update based on some condition (say, bool variable `var.overwrite_old_value`).

I can't use `overwrite =` property, because if it's set to `false` terraform will throw an exception attempting to overwrite the value

I can't use `lifecycle { ignore_chanes = [...] }` because it requires static attribute values and doesn't accept variables, functions etc.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I figured out the way

```
data aws_ssm_parameter private_key {
  count = var.overwrite_old_values? 0 : 1
  name  = var.name
}

resource aws_ssm_parameter private_key {
  name           = var.name
  type           = "SecureString"
  value          = var.overwrite_old_values? var.key : data.aws_ssm_parameter.private_key[0].value
  overwrite      = true
  tags           = var.tags
}
```

If flag is set to overwrite - I am assigning new value, otherwise the value from the SSM parameter itself, using it as data source (had to add some additional checks so the data source isn't used before parameter is created, but it works).

Comment: That's a good one, thanks for sharing the answer

Comment: @yuriy-galanter, would consider to add the additional checks you mentioned to your answer so that it doe not fail at the initial deployment?

Comment: @Rafiq I updated the answer with additional condition. Now if `overwrite_old_values` is `true` - data source will not be read (and the resource will use value from the variable). But if `overwrite_old_values` is `false` -  only then data source is read and is used as a value for the resource.

Comment: Worth noting, `data aws_ssm_parameter`, will add the value into the state file as plain text, perhaps not the best in many circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

This is not how terraform is intended to work, but you can achieve this behaviour using directly the aws api.

In this case, everytime that you run the plan you should input the `var.key` and `var.overwrite` which is the bool variable that tells terraform if the script to update the key needs to be executed.

```
resource "null_resource" "update_private_key" {
  count = var.overwrite ? 1 : 0

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws ssm put-parameter --name \"mykey\" --type \"SecureString\" --value ${var.key} --overwrite"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty interesting, unfortunately I need IDs of those resources to be used elsewhere. Also when running in CI there is no guarantee AWS CLI will be there.